# trying to run a sanity test for SPI master but test did not get picked up

Tags: python, linux, coroutine, spi, cocotb

I am new to cocotb and want to run a sanity test for SPI master. I had coded a simple test without importing driver and monitor but calling all signals from DUT. I tried running a simple test , report showed no syntax or indentation error but test is not getting pick up and finding this message "Did not detect Python virtual environment. Using system-wide Python interpreter" How to solve this?

```
import logging
import cocotb
from cocotb.triggers import RisingEdge, FallingEdge, Timer, ReadOnly
from cocotb.clock import Clock
from cocotb.result import TestFailure
import random


class MasterSpi(object):
    INTERFRAME = (100, "ns")

    def __init__(self, dut, clock, w_CPOL=0, w_CPHA=1):
        self._dut = dut
        self._w_CPOL = w_CPOL
        self._w_CPHA = w_CPHA
        if w_CPOL == 1:
            raise Exception("cpol = 1 not implemented yet")
        if w_CPHA == 0:
            raise Exception("cpha = 0 not implemented yet")
        self._clock_thread = cocotb.fork(clock.start())

        spi_sigs = SPISignals(
            miso=dut.i_SPI_MISO,
            mosi=dut.o_SPI_MOSI,
            sclk=dut.o_SPI - Clk,
        )

        self.spi_config = SPIConfig(
            w_CPOL=False,
            w_CPHA=True,
            baudrate=(1, "us"),
            csphase=False,
        )

        self.spimod = SPIModule(self.spi_config, spi_sigs, clock)


@cocotb.coroutine
def reset(self):

    print("inside coroutine")

    self._dut.i_Rst_L <= 0
    short_per = Timer(100, units="ns")
    self._dut.i_Rst_L <= 0
    self.spimod.set_ss(False)
    self._dut.o_SPI_MOSI <= 0
    self._dut.o_SPI_Clk <= 0
    yield short_per
    self._dut.i_Rst_L <= 1
    yield short_per
```

Comment: If you need cocotb extension for SPI you can take a look of this cocotbext-spi module : https://github.com/Martoni/cocotbext-spi

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a cocotb.test() anywhere there.